# Xcode4 App work fine on iPhoneSimulator,but build on Device got a armv6/7 error:(

Tags: iphone, xcode4, armv7, armv6

I'm at a lost at this point. :(
**The application is work fine iPhoneSimulator.
But when I try to build on Device(iphone4.3.1)(XCode4),**
I get the following error:

**When I choose Standard(armv6 armv7)  to build:**

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.2.3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTMessageQueueing.framework/DTMessageQueueing, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIAutomation.framework/UIAutomation, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) 
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) for architecture armv6
```

**When I choose Optimized(armv7) to build:**

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.2.3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTMessageQueueing.framework/DTMessageQueueing, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIAutomation.framework/UIAutomation, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) 
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7) for architecture armv7 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone please provide any pointers on how to resolve this issues. 
How can I resolve the unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6) for architecture armv6  errors. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the libraries mentioned and re-add them using the '+' button in 'Link Binary with Libraries' section of your target's Build Phases tab.

Comment: That doesn't help. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try going through all your build settings looking for something out-of-place? The problem (as I'm sure you've figured out) is that Xcode is looking at the simulator frameworks when trying to link for the iPhone. A last resort would be to delete your .xcodeproj file and rebuild the project in Xcode, if you're totally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve a similar problem but check/adding entries to Search Path segment of the  Build Settings for the app.

The Framework Search Paths item contains old references to `4.3 SDK` paths that were probably correct before I upgrade to `SDK 5.0`.

Whether necessary or not, I added entries under Debug for IOS Simulator 5.0 and Any IOS SDK that distinguished between the path through `iPhoneSimulator.Platform` and `iPhoneOS.Platform` directories.